# How to extract in php this type of XML format?

Tags: php, xml

How to extract in php this type of XML format? i try 'simplexml_load_file' function but its not work, it work only normal xml format.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a:p>
<a:r>
<a:rPr strike="noStrike" u="none" b="0" cap="none" baseline="0" sz="1400" lang="en-US" i="0">
<a:solidFill>
<a:srgbClr val="595959"/>
</a:solidFill>
<a:latin typeface="Arial"/>
<a:ea typeface="Arial"/>
<a:cs typeface="Arial"/>
<a:sym typeface="Arial"/>
</a:rPr>
<a:t>E-mail Address</a:t>
</a:r>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML you show isn't *well-formed*, meaning it doesn't match the *structure* of what XML should look like. Specifically, the `<a:p>` element on line 2 doesn't have an ending tag, `</a:p>`.

Adding that ending tag should make `simplexml_load_string` work, but you'll also get warnings because of having an undefined namespace, `a`. The `a:` that's part of each element name is saying those elements are part of a namespace whose alias is `a`. To fix this, you would add an attribute to your *root element* to define that alias, like this: `<a:p xmlns:a="some-namespace">` (replace *`some-namespace`* with the actual namespace for the XML content you're using, obviously--this looks like it could be the content of an MS Word Document, so the namespace might be something like `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml`, as a guess).

Once you start using the namespace correctly, though, you'll have to inform `simplexml_load_string` that the content you're loading is in that namespace; this is done via the fourth argument to the function, `ns`.

A complete, working example is:

```
<?php

$content = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a:p xmlns:a="some-namespace">
<a:r>
<a:rPr strike="noStrike" u="none" b="0" cap="none" baseline="0" sz="1400" lang="en-US" i="0">
<a:solidFill>
<a:srgbClr val="595959"/>
</a:solidFill>
<a:latin typeface="Arial"/>
<a:ea typeface="Arial"/>
<a:cs typeface="Arial"/>
<a:sym typeface="Arial"/>
</a:rPr>
<a:t>E-mail Address</a:t>
</a:r>
</a:p>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content, "SimpleXMLElement", 0, "some-namespace");

print_r($xml);

?>
```

Obviously, you'd normally be reading the XML from a file or some such, but I included it inline in a *heredoc* for simplicity.

You can look at the [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) and [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) documentation for additional helpful details.

Comment: hi sir Jonathan, thanks for the answer. yes the xml code it takes in ms power point. (pptx), i try to get the data inside the slide1.xml, 

your code works well.

Comment: any idea for to extract the data? in 'ppt/slides/slide1.xml' this xml file comes from 'presenstation.pptx' i rename it to 'presenstation.zip'